# "Fixed" positioned before pseudo element

Tags: css

How can I make the `icon::before` pseudo element not scroll. I want it to have a "fixed" position; not relative to the window, but to `div.scrollable.icon`

Here's the demo I'm talking about: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLWdEm

---

===UPDATE===

---

There's a problem here. Here's the new codepen: http://codepen.io/kiranm/pen/QbgxZV

How do I make `icon::before` "fixed" relative to `div.scrollable.icon`?

Comment: Did you try changing `position:absolute;` to `position:fixed;` in `.icon::before`?

Comment: @EricMartinez I never thought of that! thanks a lot

Comment: http://codepen.io/kiranm/pen/QbgxZV like this?

Comment: @EricMartinez apparently there's a problem with that approach. Could you take a look at my update?

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. If you want to `An icon` to be `fixed` it's working already. Your update is the same solution we suggested you.

Comment: @EricMartinez but it's `fixed` to the window, i.e: when you scroll down, the `icon::before` also scrolls although `scrollable` is not scrolling. Can I make the `icon::before` `fixed` to `scrollable` instead? Let me know if it's still not clear

Comment: See my answer please and tell me if it is what you want.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, what you want is: display an icon at the top of a body of text. And when the body of text scrolls, the icon should remain at the top of the text.

To provide a proper solution, we need to know what are your constraints: can you alter the HTML in any way? You have used background-color and text for your "icon", but is  the actual icon an image? Is adding JS an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I understood your problem. Since we all tried the code with the preview expanded we didn't see that when we shrink the preview the div was fixed relative to the window.

So I came up with this, although I couldn't do it just with CSS, I had to add a little of jQuery and modify your HTML structure.

HTML

```
<div class="scrollable">
   <div class="icon"></div>
   text
</div>
```

CSS

```
.scrollable {
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.icon {
   position: relative;
}

.icon::before {
    content: 'An icon';
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 2em;
}
```

And the jQuery

```
 var $ = jQuery || $;
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $('.scrollable').on('scroll', function() {
     var top = $('.scrollable').scrollTop() + $('.scrollable').offset().top;
     $('.icon').css({'top': top + 'px'});
   });
  });
```

As you can see I added another CSS rule so I can manipulate it with jQuery, and with jQuery I took the value of the scroll in the container div and I add to it its value to the top of the window, and I assign that result to the `top` of the `icon` so it will be "`fixed`" to the div. Also I moved the `icon` div to be a child of `scrollable` so I can manipulate it separately.

Here's the pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbgxzV

I hope it helps you.

Comment: @Eric Martinez  I applied same for horizontal scroll. But didn't work

Comment: Can you give me one solution? I am stuck with this

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://codepen.io/kiranm/pen/QbgxZV)**

```
.icon::before {
  content: 'An icon';
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 2em;
  position: fixed; / * changed position absolute to fixed */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Position fixed is working for relative to window screen only. otherwise you set icon `position:relative` then give `icon::before` `position absolute`.

Comment: but when you scroll `icon`, `icon::before` is also scrolled. I want `icon::before`, for the lack of a better word, to "fixed" to `icon` instead of the window. I hope it make sense